# Insert or update cells ([Range]) from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that gets specific range from inputsheet and then pastespecial with xlValue to just copy the values.

However, I want that if the macro runs again, it should update value if already in outputSheet otherwise insert.

what is the best way to do it?
I want to avoid looping  cells for performance.
I can modify the existing copy process to include some metadata with the values, like sourceCell.address. but with any metadata, i would still want to avoid loop.

Is there any recommended way of doing this?

Comment: Insert the new values into the top below the header and push down the existing data then Remove Dplicates (duplicates are removed from the lower of multiple values).

Comment: It's not the looping itself that's slow, but looping over a range of cells.  If you copy the range data to a Variant Array and loop _that_ it's usually fast enough

Comment: @ chris neilsen  thanks for the suggestion. i will use array in case i dont find a way to completey avoid looping. by the way my macro triggers when user changes the value in inputShteet, so im looking to get things done in very optimized  way so that user don't  see any unresponsive behavior.

Comment: @Jeeped is there a way to insert range at the top and move the rest of values down? Insert on a table allows you to insert one row and move the next row down. so if i would need to insert one by one, then there still be looping. is there a way to add/insert list of rows at first cell of the table and move existing rows down?